# get the same shape in css

Tags: html, css

I have an image. I want to make the exact shape into css. So can someone kindly tell me how to make this shape in css? Any suggesions and help will be appreciable.

**Update**
It is the smooth curve in the image

Here is the image [image]

Comment: is it smooth curve ? 
because it doesn't seem so.

Comment: Yes it is the smooth curve.

Comment: Just read a very similar question with a good response: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23904255/css-borders-bend-inside/23904395#23904395

Comment: That curve is anything but smooth.

Answer (score 3):

I made you this piece of code:

HTML:

```
<div class="shape">
    <div> </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.shape {
    background: lightblue;
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.shape > div {
    background: white;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 1000px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -150%;
    margin-top: -125%;
}
```

You need to play a bit with the widths, heights, and margins to adjust it to your needs.

Also, check [**this DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/4cMEQ/).

Comment: I want the white portion to be transparent.

Comment: You can't, alternatively use an image.

Answer (score 0):

**working**

```
<style>

#pre-container{
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 600px;
    height: 742px;
    width: 600px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
   right: 550px;
    top: -400px;

}

#post-container{
    background-color: #e5e5e5;
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: absolute;
    right: 200px;
}


</style>
<html>
    <body>
    <div id="pre-container"></div>
    <div id="post-container"></div>
</div>
    </body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The shape you have there is basically a partial circle covering a rectangle.  You can create a circle in CSS by setting a matching `height`, `width` and `border-radius`:

```
#circle {
    border-radius: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Then with some absolute positioning you can control its position within the rectangle:

```
#container {
    background-color: #aaa;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
}

#circle {
    border-radius: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;

    left: -100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -100px;
}
```

Working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/L3yP6/1/

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this by using `:before` pseudo element. I've used the `200px` height and `width`. if you change the height you have to play with `top or left` position.

In addition only one `div` is more enough to achieve this effect.

CHECK the **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/nawoyiju/1)**.

```
div{background:#008080; width:200px; height:200px;}
div:before{
  content: "";
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  top:-8px;
  left:-75px;
 background:#ffffff;
  border-radius:100%;
  transform: skewY(-40deg);
}
```